# CSS direction style won't work properly

Tags: css

If we add `direction: rtl;` in CSS then `word-wrap` and `word-break` styles are not working. How we can solve this issue in Pure CSS?

Note: I need to support browsers IE9+ and chrome

```css
#container {
  height: 440px;
  width: 150px;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #leftDiv{
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
 }
 #centreDiv{
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
 }
 #rightDiv{ 
  //word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 70px;
  float: right;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id='leftDiv'>
  Java121HTML121HTML121Javscript121
  </div>
  <div id='centreDiv'>
   ...
  </div>
  <div id='dummy'>
  <div id='rightDiv'>
  Java121HTML121HTML121Javscript121
  </div>
</div>
```

If you uncomment right div word break will change

Comment: Can you provide a working example? jsfiddle/snippet

Comment: @Dekel: Code snippet added

Comment: Yeah, noticed. Checking it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working, below is the running code and attached screenshot.

```css
div{
  direction: rtl;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteturasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis consequat augue, eget euismod quam ultricies at. Donec venenatis, turpis.</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: For me Character goes cutted

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wonkmn5p/3/ . Here is the fiddle for same. It seems like you have written overflow: hidden. I have removed that, test now.

Comment: now both side looks same, then what is the use I want to have abc...xyz

Comment: Characters should not cut off

Comment: Can't seems to understand your requirements.